# Select MAX values within records with the same name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have some polygons with same name and different area.

I want to select each polygon by name (FARM_ID field) with maximum area.

For example, I want to select polygons "SCAPD04-1" with maximum area, and polygons "SCAPD01-30 P2" with maximum area, and so on.

This data contain 700 polygons, so if I select polygons one by one, it is not effective

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simpler non-coding approach is to run your polygon dataset through the summary statistics tool extracting max area and the case field is you farm ID. Then simply join this output table to your featureclass and then select max_area where is it not NULL.

You could even wrap this up in a model to run repeatedly.

Comment: Very good, I saw the arcpy tag and dove straight in :D This is a very nice approach.

Comment: @Clubdebambos, I think it useful for future readers to see alternative approaches, so your python based approach is still very much valid, mine is just easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a handful of ways to achieve this. Here's one...

```
import arcpy

## or you can access your current mxd nd get this as a layer
fc = "path/to/fc"

id_fld = "FARM_ID"

max_fld = "area"

## get a list of unique ids from FARM_ID
def getUnique(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

## the list
unique_ids = getUnique(fc, id_fld)

## print to test
print(unique_ids)

## we will populate this list with the OBJECTIDs of the records with
## the max area values per unique id
object_ids = []

## for each entry in the unique_ids list
for entry in unique_ids:
    ## select the records for that id
    selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", "{0} = {1}".format(id_fld, entry))
    ## get the objectid for the selection when sorted descending based on area
    max_objid = [row[1] for row in sorted(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selection, [max_fld, "OBJECTID"]), reverse=True)][0]
    ## append the objectid into the list as a string
    object_ids.append(str(max_objid))

## print to test
print(object_ids)

## create an sql expression based on the list
sql_exp = "OBJECTID IN ({0})".format(",".join(object_ids))

## print to test
print(sql_exp)

## select only those objectids of interest
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", sql_exp)

## test the amount of records returned matches the number of unique ids.
print(int(arcpy.GetCount_management(selection).getOutput(0)))
```

The above is performed as a script outside of ArcMap, you can tweak it to use a layer with an MXD. Code is commented, you can remove the printing as needed.